# Instanceof for generic with <?> or without <?>

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I have a question about generics in Java and `instanceof` operator.
It's immposible to make such *instanceof check*:

```
if (arg instanceof List<Integer>)  // immposible due to
                                   // loosing parameter at runtime
```

but it's possible to run this one:

```
if (arg instanceof List<?>)
```

Now comes my question - **is there any difference between** `arg instanceof List` **and** `arg instanceof List<?>` ?

Comment: I think the former might give you a warning in the IDE: "raw type used" (dependend on the IDE you use) whereas the latter will give you no such warning. But apart from that, those two are the same. Generics are really just a compiler hint, they are discarded by the compiler.

Comment: Ok but if I have generic class `class A<T>` it is says to better do this: `A<?> tab[] = new A<?>[2]` than this: `A tab[] = new A[2]` because in this example for first one ''will be performed at least partial type check''.

Comment: Partial? You mean, it's checked whether the added object is at least instancof Object? That's not much of a type check...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java Generics are implemented by *erasure*, that is, the additional type information (`<...>`) will not be available at runtime, but erased by the compiler. It helps with static type checking, but not at runtime.

Since `instanceof` will perform a check at runtime, not at compile time, you can not check for `Type<GenericParameter>` in an `instanceof ...` expression.

As to your question (you probably seem to know already that the generic parameter is not available at runtime) there is no difference between `List` and `List<?>`. The latter is a wildcard which basically expresses the same thing as the type without parameters. It's a way of telling the compiler "I know that I don't know the exact type in here".

`instanceof List<?>` boils down to `instanceof List` - which are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes I know this very well and even wrote it in my question @scarvy ;) But my question is about something else - read carefully

Comment: edited that in (should have read more carefully) - I hope that answers it now?

Answer (score 2):

`List and List < ? >` are not same but in this case when you using with **instanceof** operator they mean the same thing.

**instanceof** cann't be used with Generics as Generics doesn't store any type information at run time (due to erasure implementation).

This point gets cleared by below main method. I have declared two list (one of Integer type and other of String type). And **instanceof** behave same for `List and List < ? >`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(l instanceof List<?>){
        System.out.print("<?> ");
    }

    if(l instanceof List){
        System.out.print("l ");
    }

    if(ls instanceof List<?>){
        System.out.print("<?> ");
    }

    if(ls instanceof List){
        System.out.print("ls ");
    }
     }
```

output is : 
`<?> l <?> ls`

In above main method all if statements are true. So it clear that in this case `List and List<?>` are same.

Comment: I'm not asking about execution results - it's obvious that they will be the same but about just the rule. Is `instanceof List<?>` just a nice-looking-and-doing-nothing language extra ?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I just tried to stress same using example because Generics is confusing so it helps to check through example :)